# Low-resolution (ldpi) Android icons

Tags: android, icons

On the topic of included standard icons the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) mentions that:

> Shown below are standard menu icons
>   that are used in the Android system.
>   Because these resources can change
>   between platform versions, you should
>   not reference the system's copy of the
>   resources. If you want use any icons
>   or other internal drawable resources,
>   you should store a local copy of those
>   icons or drawables in your application
>   resources, then reference the local
>   copy from your application code. In
>   that way, you can maintain control
>   over the appearance of your icons,
>   even if the system's copy changes.
>   Note that the list below is not
>   intended to be complete.

In my application I'm using such standard icons such as "ic_menu_sort_alphabetically" and thus I've tried to find these icons, so that I can include them in my application.

However, in "android-sdk/platforms/android-8/android.jar" I only find the icons in drawable-mdpi and in drawable-hdpi - there is neither a default drawable folder with icons, nor a drawable-ldpi folder with low-resolution versions of these icons. However, such a low-resolution version would be required to provide native versions on ldpi devices such as the HTC Wildfire.

Are there any "official" versions of the Android icons scaled at ldpi? While it's likely that the ldpi versions are stored somewhere on my HTC Wildfire device, I assume that they are copyrighted by HTC and not under the same open-source license as the icons in the Android distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find the pre-scaled images, you can just open the mdpi in Photoshop or GIMP and resize them by 75% to make the ldpi icons.  To make hdpi resize the mdpi image by 150%.